# NetSuite Suitecommerce Page source

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

I'm new to suite commerce and I couldn't find page source.

Clicking a tag it goes to page.

Here a tag is.

```
<a href="/s.nl/it.I/id.51/.f?fromsla=T">CONTACT</a>
```

Where could I find page source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL indicates that you are trying to find the template that lays out Information Item with Internal Id 51.

So in Netsuite:
go to Lists -> Website -> Information Items -> Search
use "Advanced Search" with criteria to find Internal Id (Number) is 51. 
If you are just trying to change the html then one of the info item's description fields may be what you need to edit.

If you are trying to get to the markup then check if that item has an "Item DrillDown Template". If it does then go to Setup -> Site Builder -> Item/Category Templates and find and edit the referenced template.

Otherwise you need to find the Info Item Drilldown template. This could be specified at the web site level or at on the web site's theme.